# TFS 2015 build - Get Sources is taking too long time (5 minutes)

Tags: tfs, build, tfsbuild

I tested here a build with only one text file, and I got this:

[image: Only Get sources took 5 minutes!!!!]

It's thes same for all builds, the Get sources takes 5 minutes. Even when I set to keep the workspace.

Any idea how to speed up that or what could be the reason for that delay?

Comment: I agree, that is high. What is your `Logging Verbosity` set at?

Comment: Did your another task in the build definition also takes  too long time than normal？

Comment: My custom task that does lot of stuff take seconds... seems something wrong with my server.

Comment: You could try to build with another build agent. Or edit your build definition without the custom task and. try it again.

Comment: I did it, see the conclusion below... it was a issue related with the mapping a specific file instead of a folder.

Answer (score 3):

Might be network speed(If you build on one server and then move the files to another network share), or problem with disk on the server(busy or slow disk), or Anitvirus(blocking and checking each file that is being copied to the buildarea/network endpoint. Etc.

Answer (score 2):

I found a kind of bug I guess. This is the solution for this case.

I had mapped a small file to have a quick test of my custom task:
[image: File.txt mapped - Don't do it!]
For me it didn't show any error, but I notice the slowness in the Get sources:
[image: 5 minutes of slowness!!!]

Then checking the agent's working folder, it was creating a file "s" instead of a folder "s", as usual! AND THIS IS THE ISSUE. Seems that it can't handle well singles files mapped.

Then I tested with:
[image: Folder mapped :)]
Look the result:
[image: 0.20 seconds!!!]

Instead of 5 minutes it took 0.23 seconds! Seems a joke but it's not!

For me it's a bug. Thank you all for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

The detail steps with **Get Source** often including below :

- Syncing repository XXX
- Deleting files （seems not related to this one）
- Recreating  missing folders on disk
- Redownload missing folders on disk
- tf get /version(Changeset ID)
- Syncing repository

You can double check  which step takes longer than normal time to narrow down the issue.